# Mongodb how to fetch all matching records from two diffrent collections in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'am trying to fetch related result from deposits and coin_infos collections, but i am getting empty user array.

```
> db.deposits.aggregate([{ $lookup: { from: 'coin_infos', localField: 
'coin_key', foreignField: '_id', as: 'user' } }]).pretty();
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a4b0f4a32c51230087a5453"),
"user_id" : "5a4b0787a0050c20a6be44b2",
"coin_key" : "5a4b07b2a0050c20a6be44b3",
"label" : "Test",
"address" : "17dhdZSEtoabadme6M9WBnqS4n6WU3ycJm",
"__v" : 0,
"user" : [ ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coin_key` is a string in your case. It should have been an `ObjectId`. mongodb just does an equality match. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

If you are using v3.6, then you could take a look at the *Join Conditions and Uncorrelated Sub-queries* section on the same page.

Comment: can i find the match record of 'user_id' like where condition. means i want all records of particular user_ids.

Comment: I think you can add the `$match` stage in the pipeline before the lookup - if that's what your question means. I can't be of more help without taking a look at your `coin_infos` document schema.